# Loop to load .dat files

Tags: matlab, loops, load

I want to load  13 .dat files that I have stored in a folder. When doing this:

```
dir 'C:\modelana\psteptrue\' %folder where are the files I want to load
myFiles = dir ('*.dat');
for days=1:13
    myData = load(myFiles(days).name);
end
```

I just can get on my workspace the last file in the folder. Like it detects all the files I want to read. But I only get the data of the last one stored.

What am I missing there?

Comment: You have a make `myData` a struct array, by doing `myData(days) = load(myFiles(days).name);`

Comment: Thank you four your answer, but know with your update I get the following error:

'Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements '

My .dat files all have 6 columns and different rows number.

Comment: Ah, if the number of rows is variable you may want to put the data in a cell array, by using curly braces: `myData{days} = load(myFiles(days).name);`. If all the data has equal dimensions you could have done it with `myData(:, :, days) = load... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow. I wrapped up the solution of @rinkert in full code to point out some other room for improvements of your code.

Make everything flexible. That is, you can use the function `fullfile` to build paths, which fit your operation system. In particular when loading the files, they needed to be in your working directory. In this way below, they can be stores anywhere  =)

The same is true with looping. Check the `length` of the variable you want to look over.

And finally, allocate your memory before the loop. Because MATLAB stores data consistently and therefore has to copy it to a different location in your RAM if the variables grows.

```
% path to folder
p2fldr = 'C:\modelana\psteptrue';
% get list of files with a certain extension
Lst = dir( fullfile(p2fldr,'*.dat') ); 

% allocate memory
myData = cell(length(Lst),2);
% loop through files
for i = 1:length(Lst)
    % create path 2 file
    p2fl = fullfile(Lst(i).folder,Lst(i).name);
    % load file
    Dat = load( p2fl );
    % assign loaded date to cell-array
    myData{i,1} = Dat;
    % you may wan to keep the corresponding path/filename
    myData{i,2} = p2fl;
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.But now, I just get the last .dat file stored in my workspace. I get all the files stored in myData (13x2 cell) but when loading the file I just get Dat 7105x6 double, corresponding to the last .dat file. And what I would like to have is Dat1, Dat2,..., Dat13 on my workspace

Comment: no, you don't want this. This would mean that you cannot do looping ;) That is why you store everything in a cell array, over which you can loop. Creating independent variables (even if they have the same name-pattern) is never recommended in any programming language